# Are there any pre-check-in shops at Mumbai Airport?

Tags: india, shopping, mumbai, bom

Are there any shops at Mumbai Airport, where I could make shopping prior to checking in? Of course, that would not be duty free, but that's not a problem for me.

I have found [airport's page for shops](http://csia.in/shopanddine/shop.aspx), but either I'm searching incorrectly or all of them are available post check-in and after passing security control. Just want to confirm this.

I'll be flying from international terminal (Terminal 2), but since I'm asking for pre-check-in shopping, then this shouldn't matter.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[The airport webpage on shopping lists all the shops ordered by terminal.](http://csia.in/shopanddine/shop.aspx) If you select Terminal 2 International and click on each one of the shops listed, you'll see that a few of them are found before security. These are:

> #### Jaya He Museum Store
>
> Jaya He Museum Store offers exquisite art, craft and design based collectibles made by renowned and upcoming artists of India. Pick exquisite art and craft forms in contemporary styles inspired by the Jaya He GVK New Museum at T2.  The Museum store also feature an exhibition outlet selling real time works of celebrated artists in the original form as well as product adaptations.
>
> Location: Departures, Level 4
>
> #### Kama Ayurveda
>
> Browse through Kama Ayurveda’s treatment based and Internationally acclaimed holistic solutions for the skin, hair and body made with pure, natural and organic ingredients.
>
> Location: Terminal 2, Level 3, South-west pier, International Departures
>
> #### Xpress
>
> Xpress is a one-stop airport shop for a wide assortment of books & magazines, choicest Indian snacks, beverages, gift items, toys and daily essentials. Stopover to pick up a few essentials before you board.
>
> Location:
>
> - Level 4, International Departures, Before Security Check
> - Level 2, International to Domestic Transfer Area
> - Level 3, International Departures, After Security Check, South West Pier

I'm not sure what `opposite security checks` means, but there might even be a pharmacy available at Terminal 2:

> #### Apollo Pharmacy
>
> Forgot first aid for the long trip? Headache? Tummy trouble? Head to the Apollo Pharmacy for all your medical needs.
>
> Location : Departures - Opposite Security Check Area - 1

I'll let you search for available shops in the remaining terminals.